# How to parallelize Windows message loop and hook callback logic and the Ruby threads it creates?

Tags: c, ruby, multithreading, winapi, callback

I'm working on a free, simple, hopefully multi-platform hotkey launcher tool, written in Ruby.

Right now I'm struggling with some threading issues of the Windows implementation.
The rough proof of concept code shown below already **works reliably** in my day-to-day use:

**HotkeyProcessor#process_keypress** (**footnote 1**) gets called by the C code when a key is pressed and subsequently handles the key event.

### Problem

However, when **process_keypress** *starts a thread* that does some time consuming work (**footnote 2**), a subtle flaw shows up:
The program spends most of its time in the C extension, waiting for **get_message** (**footnote 3**) to return - which by design never happens. Ruby threads aren't run in the meanwhile.
Thread execution only happens while Ruby-level code is in control, thus only for the few miliseconds after every key event when #process_keypress is active.

Is continually concurrent execution possible in this context?
Thanks for any suggestions!

```
require 'hotkey_processor'

def slowly_do_stuff
  5.times { |i| sleep(0.1); print "#{i} " }
end

module HotkeyProcessor
  def self.process_keypress(code, down) # footnote 1
    print '. '
    slowly_do_stuff              if code == 65 and down # A pressed
    Thread.new {slowly_do_stuff} if code == 66 and down # B pressed # footnote 2
    true
  end
end
puts 'Press A, B and other keys.'
HotkeyProcessor.start
```

HotkeyProcessor:

```
#include "ruby.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int process_keypress_function;
VALUE HotkeyProcessor;
HHOOK keyboard_hook;

LRESULT CALLBACK callback_function(int Code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbd = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;

  if (Code < 0 || Qtrue == rb_funcall(HotkeyProcessor, 
                                      process_keypress_function,
                                      2,
                                      INT2NUM(kbd->vkCode), /* code */
                                      (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || 
                                       wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) ? 
                                         Qtrue : Qfalse)) /* down */
  {
    return CallNextHookEx(keyboard_hook, Code, wParam, lParam);
  }
  else
    return 1;
}

static BOOL get_message(MSG *msg)
{
  return GetMessage(msg, 0, 0, 0);
}

static VALUE start(VALUE self)
{
    HMODULE Module = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    MSG msg;

    keyboard_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, 
                                     (HOOKPROC) callback_function, 
                                     Module, 
                                     0);

    get_message(&msg); /* footnote 3 */

    /* Never get here. Wait forever for get_message() to return
       to keep the program alive and responding to callbacks. */
    return self;
}

static VALUE process_keypress(VALUE self, VALUE code)
{
  return Qnil;
}

void Init_hotkey_processor() {
  HotkeyProcessor = rb_define_module("HotkeyProcessor");
  rb_define_module_function(HotkeyProcessor, 
                            "process_keypress", 
                            process_keypress, 
                            1);
  rb_define_module_function(HotkeyProcessor, 
                            "start", 
                            start, 
                            0);
  process_keypress_function = rb_intern("process_keypress");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the Windows message loop via 'rb_thread_blocking_region' and wrap 'rb_thread_call_with_gvl' around the Ruby API calls that take place in the callback function.

See here for a **working demo**: [git clone git://github.com/kaysarraute/ruby-win32-callback-threading.git](http://github.com/kaysarraute/ruby-win32-callback-threading/)

---

```
/* Release the Giant VM Lock (GVL) while calling pump_messages */
rb_thread_blocking_region(pump_messages, 0, 0, 0);
```

---

```
static BOOL pass_key_event_to_ruby(struct KEYEVENT *key_event) {
  /* Ruby API calls go here. */
}

/* In the callback: Reacquire GVL for calls to the Ruby API. */
rb_thread_call_with_gvl(pass_key_event_to_ruby, &key_event);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you are doing, but how about using [PeekMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644943%28VS.85%29.aspx) which does return?